# How do I track and compare SQL Scripts from VS to the Database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, version-control

I have a view and a stored proc and a table that I want to keep track of.

Normally, what gets done is I script all these out from SSMS and then put it in my Solution in Visual Studio.

Is there a way to connect these scripts in a sense to the database so it can compare when, say the stored proc has been changed on the database server?

I was trying to use SQL Server Project in Visual Studio but I am not sure if it is geared for that as that will track the changes in the WHOLE database. I just need it to track changes for 2 or 3 particular stored procs?

Comment: The SQL Server project, as you mentioned, is exactly what you need. You can select which objects from your database to import, and which objects to run a Schema Compare or Data Compare on.

Comment: yes start using `TFS` and add the Sql Server project to your Solution and if you don't have that then you will have to run a `Schema Compare` or get a program where you can manually compare both files.. also with TFS in regards to Database changes if someone does the change outside of Visual Studio using TFS.. then those will get lost and or overwritten in  your decided to edit and or make changes to one that was not checked in it's best to have everyone in your group or organization get onboard with one consistant practice or method of checking in and out changes